# VS Code $msCompile problemMatcher doesn't work with relative file path

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, dotnet-cli, vscode-problem-matcher

I need to compile a .NET solution using Visual Studio Code.
My task inside `tasks.json` is declared like:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> I can successfully compile my entire solution. Unfortunately `dotnet build` seems to output relative file path, and from the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_processing-task-output-with-problem-matchers) the `$msCompile` problem matcher works only with absolute path. The effect is that when there is an error clicking on it inside the Problems panel produce the error `Unable to open XYZ.cs: File not found`.

How can I correctly configure `dotnet build` or problemMatcher to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy solution is to let `dotnet build` produce absolute file path by using `/property:GenerateFullPaths=true` argument.
This is a working task definition:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```